# Python convention for overriding bad names

Tags: python, pylint, pep8, convention

I'm writing a file that subclasses `npycurses.ActionFormV2` from the `npycurses` [module](http://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/index.html), and I'm overriding the `beforeEditing` [method](http://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/application-objects.html?highlight=beforeEditing#Form.beforeEditing) , so when I lint my file, I get the [C0103](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0103) error because I don't conform to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id46). 
What's the best, most pythonic convention for obeying PEP8 when overriding a method with a non PEP8 name? I don't want to disable C0103 entirely, but these errors are quite annoying. Is there a way to get pylint to ignore C0103 when overriding something?

I'm sure this issue comes up a lot for people since there are a lot of community packages out there that don't obey conventions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer which i missed in my initial searching because of pylint's minimal documentation :P

You can just add inline message to pylint in the code to disable certain rules:

```
def beforeEditing(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
```